# Video rendering issue after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, video-conversion, video-editing, video-encoding

I'm using a GoPro Hero7 Black for making some family and amateur videos, Sometimes I used Quick application for short clips and sometimes I used Davinci Resolve 15 for more complicated things..
Recently I updated my Windows 10 to the latest version, suddenly Davinci Resolve wouldn't open with this issue "No OpenCL Hardware Acceleration Detected" .
To quick fix the issue I uninstalled it and put Davinci Resolve 16 instead, It run but I remarked an very degradation in video quality, even with 4K resolution.
[image]
I thought it's Davinci Resolve 16 issue because it stills in beta , I rolled back to 15, but the problem remains, at the same time I found that quick videos are in poor quality too..
So I think it's a Windows 10 update who ruined something..

Any help please

Comment: "I updated my Windows 10 to the latest version" - What version is that?  There are multiple versions that are current.  Please edit your question to include this information.  You should also indicate which cumulative update you most recently installed.

Comment: I update the question with image, i hope it's enough